# Recovering BCH sent to BTC Ledger Nano S Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet, cross-chain-recovery

I've looked at existing  relevant threads, but still I didn't got the right solution for my situation, so raising this request. This case is perhaps somewhat different because it relates specifically to a Ledger hardware wallet.

I was trying to transfer BCH from Koinex wallet to my Ledger Nano S wallet, but I've given BTC address wrongly instead of BCH address! The transaction was succesfully sent from the Koinex site, however I've not received my coins into my Ledger Nano S wallet as I've given BTC address instead of BCH! When I see the transaction status in Block Chain, I was surprised, there were 63 confirmations till now! I wonder how it is possible as I've given wrong wallet id.

Anyway, I would like advice on how to retrieve my coins.

Comment: Dear Admin(s), the thread seems to be duplicate, but it is not. I've gone thru all the relevant threads but didn't find solution for my issue. thus, raised this thread. Kindly help me to get responses and solution. Thanks

Comment: I voted to reopen this, because the linked question is about transferring to an address in an exchange, whereas this is about transferring to a hardware wallet where the user holds the key.